# How to use html form data for fpdf form creation

Tags: php, mysql, html, email, fpdf

i am trying to create a pdf email using data inputed into a html form. I don't know how to use data from a mysql database or html form to create a pdf using fpdf and email it. I am close to finishing this project i have been working on and need help closing off the deal i have a difficult html form using specially spaced tables and such trying to reproduce a excel document to a html form doing javascript calculations and now all i need to do is email this form in a pdf format using php or something using my linux webserver. please i really want to know this for myself as well. i have learned alot in the past few weeks about html,php,mysql, and javascript and i started this as a project for fun and now people want it. Sorry. And thank you all for all your help for teaching me this information. ok heres the code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
 <?php
 $intro = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['intro']);
 $hostname ="localhost";
 $db_user = "someuser";
 $db_password = "somepassword";
 $database = "form_something";
 $db_table = "FORM";
 $db = mysql_connect ($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
 mysql_select_db($database,$db);
 ?>
  <title><h2>this is my form</h2><title>
  <?php
  if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
  # THIS CODE TELLS MYSQL TO INSERT THE DATA FROM THE FORM INTO MY MYSQL TABLE 
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(information) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['information']))."')";
  if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$db)) { 
  echo <h1>Thank you</h1>information has been entered into our database<br><img   src="http://someimage.com/here/is/the/image.jpg"';
 {
 p
 } else 
 { 
 echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error(); 
 }
 } else 
 {
 ?>
  ?>
  </head>
  <form action="pdf.php">
  <td colspan="2">type your information here<input type="text" name="information">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
  </body>
  </form>
  </html>
```

and the basic fpdf page pdf.php looks like this

```
 <?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
 {
 // Page header
function Header()
{
// Logo
$this->Image('logo.png',140,6,60);
// Arial bold 15
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
// Move to the right
$this->Cell(60);
 // Title
$this->Cell(80,10,' Form',1,0,'C');
// Line break
$this->Ln(20);
}

function Footer()
{
// Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
$this->SetY(-15);
// Arial italic 8
$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
// Page number
$this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: One thing at a time. First make sure browsers post the right parameters, then make php use these parameters correctly. There is no point throwing all the codes up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it to be pretty intuitive linking a HTML form with FPDF. Make your form in HTML, in this example I'm creating a Text Field and an Option Menu. Note that i create the form with the tag `action="to_pdf.php"` which will link the form values with php.

```
<form action="to_pdf.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="name">

    <p>Priority</p>
    <select name="priority" size="1">
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Then import the form values into your php file, the one that we already stated on the HTML, `to_pdf.php`

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];

require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

$pdf->MultiCell(40,10,$name);
$pdf->MultiCell(40,10,$priority);

$pdf->Output(); 

?>
```

After that, you only need to make sure that you have the `fpdf.php` file in the path you stated. And remember to run your test on a web server or on localhost so the php files actually run.